# Why is my div element not draggable?

Tags: jquery, draggable

Self explanatory, I should be able to move this element around since it is draggable but I can't move it, what am I doing wrong?

I can't seem to dinf any errors as the code is fairly simple

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

$('#dragThis').draggable(
    {
        drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        }
    });
```

```css
#dragThis {
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
    border:1px dashed black;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148836.png');
}
```

```html
<div id="dragThis">
<ul style="position:absolute; left:-25px; top:-25px;">
        <li id="posX"></li>
        <li id="posY"></li>
        <li id="finalX"></li>
        <li id="finalY"></li>
    </ul>
<div style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; width:10px; height:10px; background-color:grey; z-index:1000; border-radius:50%; border:1px solid black; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: draggable is part of jqueryui. you need to include jqueryui too

Answer (score 1):

> You are missing necessary dependencies.

You also have to add `jquery-ui.css` and `jquery-ui.js` files from jQueryUI. Check this [draggable demo](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) on jQueryUI site.

Working code,

```js
$('#dragThis').draggable(
    {
        drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        }
    });
```

```css
#dragThis {
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
    border:1px dashed black;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148836.png');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dragThis">
<ul style="position:absolute; left:-25px; top:-25px;">
        <li id="posX"></li>
        <li id="posY"></li>
        <li id="finalX"></li>
        <li id="finalY"></li>
    </ul>
<div style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; width:10px; height:10px; background-color:grey; z-index:1000; border-radius:50%; border:1px solid black; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to import jQueryUI.
https://code.jquery.com/ui/

**.draggable is part of jQueryUI.**

When inspecting the code in firebug or alike, the error 
`TypeError: "draggable" is not a function` helps. Check your debug :)